# Does the Stack Overflow software have a name?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-overflow-name

Does the software that runs the Stack Overflow sites have a name? I've always thought that, just as Slashdot's software is named "Slash," Stack Overflow's software should be named "Stack" or "The Stack."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While brainstorming with some colleagues about StackExchange sites, I started calling them, collectively, "**Stacks**."

I wasn't thinking about the metaphor "stacks" when I coined it but it seemed like an **effective buzzword**.

<sup>*Note: I am trying precariously to write this without using the word "paradigm."*</sup>

The metaphor describes "*a virtual exchange of ideas which is organized, not in linear time, but by the perceived merit of its content; a communication stream which forms through on-going contribution and is organized through a voting process where the most widely accepted ideas are presented first. Status and responsibility in the community of contributors rises in proportion of the abundance and popularity of their contributions.*"

Of course "stack overflow" is a programming term but there is the fortunate, but indeliberate, **parallel meaning of "stack"** as in:

- an extensive arrangement of books and other information resources
- a large number or amount; an orderly pile
- to arrange the order of so as to increase one's chance of winning

I believe that the StackExchange framework will make enough of an impact on online collaboration to merrit a coined term. Where someone might say "Google it," they may also say "Check the Stacks."

Enjoy,

Robert C. Cartaino

Answer (score 4):

If StackExchange manages to avoid forking, it would make sense to just call it that. That's the new "generic" name, really. It's a bit revisionist admittedly, but if StackOverflow is basically just one site using the StackExchange software, I don't see much reason to differentiate.

Of course, if the hosted version has a bunch of other things which aren't then in the SO branch, that's a bit different.