# What is the story of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange-history

We all know how important the team when making an idea and a great product.

In my opinion, Stack Overflow is revolutionizing the idea of forums. In other words, Stack Overflow is revolutionizing the web.

I was looking over the [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/about), and I'm curious about how the team members found each other and started working on the same product. Stack Overflow team members have different ages and different locations. Maybe one or two were friends before, but what about the rest?

What is the history of, or story behind, Stack Overflow?

Comment: New movie coming out: "Closed in 60 Seconds"

Comment: @John, it's so slow only because we read the question :-P

Comment: I completely disagree. SO is not a forum, it's not revolutionary and it's not going to change the web. It's just really well polished and scores very high on usability.

Comment: I agree with Welbog. Nothing that StackOverflow does could be considered new or revolutionary. It takes ideas from multiple areas to create a system for Q&A, something that has been huge on the internet for a while now (Yahoo! Answers). All that StackOverflow has done is make a system that for all intents and purposes does what it sets out to do better than the others.

Comment: True that Stackoverflow incorporates ideas from existing sites but has anyone else implemented a system where the "Q&A thread" is ordered, not by date of post, but by the "popularity" of the contribution? I think that's where the main innovation lies. I was speculating about its impact here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5534/does-the-stack-overflow-software-have-a-name/5619#5619

Comment: "has anyone else implemented a system where the "Q&A thread" is ordered, not by date of post, but by the "popularity" of the contribution?" Well, dozens of sites.

Answer (score 6):

The story can't be as entertaining as the fanfic I could write about it.

Comment: This fanfic: would it be erotic?

Comment: Pesto: Is there any other kind?

Answer (score 6):

Remember reading this one by Joel Spolsky

[How Hard Could It Be?: The Unproven Path](http://www.inc.com/magazine/20081101/how-hard-could-it-be-the-unproven-path.html)

Comment: That fanfic stinks. There are no ponies!