# Can we allow MATH questions on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, math-se

Math is a fundamental used in many programming languages.

In a way, one could look at programming languages as supersets of math.

What's the harm?

Comment: I failed maths in Year 11 and 12 and I failed it at University as well. I think my lecturer gave me a Pass Conceded to get me out of her class. Programmer != mathematician!

Comment: Some alternatives are listed at MathOverflow's [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot).

Comment: In a way, one could look at programming question as a subset of all questions. There's a reason we're not Yahoo!® Answers. I'm assuming, of course, that you mean `subsets` unless you take programming to be larger than math.

Comment: @waiwai933, can you help me make a trajectory calculation algorithm for my homing missiles in the new Gumby vs. Blockheads game I'm making?

Comment: @macek: Here's some very basic info on physics: http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=tzQICYOJSSgDueCK9BfUZOA&single=true&gid=0&&output=html You can use parametrics for plotting where the ind. variable is time. :) Seriously, however, if you have a problems with the physics part or with understanding how parametrics work, then SO is not the place. If you have a problem with *implementing* parametric in a language, then SO is suitable.

Answer (score 7):

In response to Arjan's suggestion, MathOverflow is really for professional mathematicians, and unless you already have a degree in math your questions are likely to be closed as off topic. In addition, since Stack Overflow is for programming questions, the only math questions that are relevant there are those dealing with programming.

However, there is [a proposal in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5534/proposal-for-mathematics-se) for a mathematics SE site for regular people. I suggest you vote on that question to show your support, and hopefully it will be created as a StackExchange 2.0 site.

Comment: I like the implication that professional mathematicians are irregular people ;-)

Answer (score 6):

My approach has been to separate math questions into a few categories:

1. The math can not be evaluated in advance, or in closed form and *will be implemented in code*. **OK** This includes all questions in numeric methods.
2. The question relates to how math can be represented in code or to the risks of treating coded math as if it were the real thing. **Mostly OK**, but also probably a duplicate: we're done most of the easy topics in this realm.
3. The question relates to writing computer algebra systems. **Obviously OK** To *using* computer algebra systems? Depends. Is it Turing complete? Can you write scripts in it? If so, keep it. If not send it to Super User.
4. The math is being evaluated in advance *in order to avoid doing it in code*. **Not OK**
5. The question relates to the mathy aspects of computer science in a purely abstract way. `computerScience != programming` so, **Not OK**

Comment: I think regardless of how specialized a question may get, if it is well formulated, has a specific answer, and lies under the umbrella of programming, why not let someone answer it?

Comment: @macek: the problem isn't questions that are "specialized", the problem is questions that are **off topic**. Here is what the faq says *"What kind of questions can I ask here? Programming questions, of course!"* What it *doesn't* say is "Questions that programmers wonder about" or "Things that interest programmers" or "Things that come up when you're writing a program", it says "Programming questions". Math you do in order to *not write code* is deeply interesting and valuable and also off topic.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make sense to field purely mathematics-related questions because they *happen* to be a stumbling block to the programmer. They belong in a specialized forum for that purpose.

By your logic, I should be able to about physics and the behavior of gravity because it was part of the simulations I have written; how about talking about poker strategy when I was writing high-speed poker evaluators; we should talk about the stock market when I was writing some data mining applications. Or, let's talk about color theory because I wrote some photo manipulation software awhile back and I got stuck with *those* problems.

Mathematics is a field in and unto itself and not a topic of computer science or programming.

Comment: Yea, i think we should be able to discuss all aspects of any programming. Sure, there's going to be niche questions, but there's a good chance someone has the know-how to answer them. Isn't that the whole point?

If i want to implement realistic jumping in my platformer game, I'd probably ask a question about a gravity equation. Talking about poker strategy if you're implementing AI is not entirely useless if you can build a good question around it. All of these things are debatable. My point is, if you can build a suitable question within the realm of programming, why not let someone answer?

Comment: Because then you end up with a site where you can talk about anything. It has been a long-held, core belief  of these site--and maybe someone can chime in with a reference here--that a site needs well defined boundaries to define their scope. When you can simply talk about anything, the site fails. I've seen way too many forums fail in *just* that manner so I believe in the premise 100-million percent.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess: This question is related to [this closed question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663744/math-how-to-sum-each-row-of-a-matrix-closed)?

I'd argue that the closure is correct, *partially* because in the question, you explicitly state:

> ## Note:
>
> I'm not looking for
>   programming-related algorithms here. I
>   want to know if it is possible to
>   represent this with pure mathematical
>   functions alone.

That pretty much makes it **not programming-related.**

Moving past that, I consider myself a pretty decent programmer. I'm no rock star, and I'm definitely not egotistical enough to call myself "good." But I do my job, I do it well, I keep learning, and (as one should do) keep getting better.

I suck at math. Royally suck at math. As in, would likely have not gotten admitted to most reputable CS programs on account of how awful I am at it.

As others have said, math != programming. Not in any way, shape nor form. Yes, math is sometimes needed for certain applications of programming, but to say one is a subset (or superset) of the other is a fallacy. Thinking in terms of a Venn diagram, there is an *intersection* between the two -- but even that border zone, unless it requires code to get there, is inappropriate for Stack Overflow.

By your logic of letting anything related to developing a software program go, I could ask questions (these last two weeks alone) on:

- The stock market
- Banks and lending
- The entertainment industry's business practices
- Logistics for handling inventory in a warehouse

Obviously, **not a one** of those topics is Stack Overflow material. Thus, neither is math, unless you need help converting your math into code.

Answer (score 1):

> Math is a fundamental used in many
>   programming languages.

No, some forms of arithmetic evaluation are implemented in them.

> In a way, one could look at
>   programming languages as supersets of
>   math.

Following from Turing et al, a subset, surely.

> What's the harm?

Programming is basically not mathematics. I think of myself as a pretty good programmer, but as  a rotten mathematician, when I think of myself as one at all. The two fields only really intersect  because they happen to use some common notation.

Comment: Subjective. Maybe your programs don't involve math beyond `1+1=2`.

Comment: @macek Computers can't do math beyond 1+1=2

Comment: @Neil: I was under the impression that computers did 1(2)+1(2)=11(2), where anything in parentheses should be in subscript (because of the base).

Comment: @waiwai: you mistyped **1(2)+1(2)=10(2)**

Comment: @quack: I stand corrected.

Comment: My point was that computers can't do anything except basic arithmetic (and can't understand what they are doing while they do it) - that's not mathematics.

Comment: @waiway,@quack... you really mean 1+1=0 with the carry bit set!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that require the formatting options like used at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)?

(**Beware**: [apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/mathoverflow-net-how-can-we-get-members-of-so-sf-su-sites-to-stop-recommending-it-inappropriately), MathOverlow is only for [very advanced](https://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatquestions), research-level questions by mathematicians.)

Comment: The guys at Mathsoverflow don't like us pushing traffic their way - their site is a very high level site for university professors and whatnot

Comment: @Farseeker, indeed I didn't know [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/mathoverflow-net-how-can-we-get-members-of-this-site-and-the-so-sf-su-sites-to-s) until I read Kyle's answer. Still, I stand by my statement about *the formatting*. Wouldn't (little) advanced mathematical questions require that? (If one could do with the SO formatting, then I guess the question would be about programming after all.)

Comment: @Farseeker, read his original post. He didn't recommend I ask questions there. He simply suggested support math-related questions would require additional formatting support on StackOverflow.